# Publish a Message with schema id with kafka-python

Tags: kafka-python

I am using [kafka-python](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) and I publish to a [strimzi](https://strimzi.io/) broker with schema registry an avro serialized message. The schema is already registered on the broker.

My code looks like the following:

```
schema = avro.schema.parse(open("schema.avsc", "rb").read())
ssl_produce = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='xxx',
                     security_protocol='xxx',
                     sasl_mechanism='xxx',
                     sasl_plain_username='xxx',
                     sasl_plain_password='xxx')

obj=    { "XXX": True}
buf = io.BytesIO()
encoder = BinaryEncoder(buf)
writer = DatumWriter(schema)
writer.write(obj, encoder)
buf.seek(0)
message_data = (buf.read())

ssl_produce.send('xxxx', key=b'xxxF', value=message_data)
```

On the broker, the message seems not be associated with a schema: what I am doing wrong? Can I add somewhere the schema id?